# Statistics on Poisson Process

Tags: statistics

Phone calls are received at a certain residences as a Poisson process with parameter lamda = 2 per hour between 8am and 5pm, and there are no calls after 5pm or before 8am. Now Diane wants to take a 7-day travel. Let X denote the number of calls during her travel, what is the probability that X is more than 150?

(1) 0.3672
(2) Approximately 0
(3) 0.0836
(4) 0.4245

I am kinda stuck here because I can't seem to get the answer listed in the choices. Any help?

Comment: Did you change the parameter? What are the average number of phone calls per day? What are the average number of phone calls per week? Use the new value of the parameter and compute the probability of $P(X>150)=1-P(X\leq 150)$

Comment: Please type out your attempt, help could be found in there...

Comment: I did not change the parameters. The questions is just what my professor wrote.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96232/poisson-process-and-probability-phone-calls I know it is found here but this time the question is different. We suppose to compute P(X>150)

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: I got 0.026 though.